# Documentation for Firebase WebSocket protocol

Tags: firebase

Is there some sort of documentation describing the Firebase WebSocket protocol (used in firebase realtime database)? I know the sources were open sourced recently ( e.g. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk ) but I was wondering if there is something easily readable so I don't have to read / debug thru the code.

Also any docs how to debug the code locally would be terrific.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*firebaser here*

The Firebase Database wire protocol is currently undocumented.

But since the questions is related to debugging the wire protocol, might be good to mention how to turn on debug logging (which shows traffic over sockets):

- JS: `firebase.database.enableLogging(true);`
- iOS: `[FIRDatabase setLoggingEnabled:YES];`
- Android: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBU‌​G);`

Comment: But since the questions is related to debugging the wire protocol, might be good to mention how to turn on debug logging (which shows traffic over sockets):  JS:  `firebase.database.enableLogging(true);`
iOS:  `[FIRDatabase setLoggingEnabled:YES];`
Android:  `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG);`