# Javascript WebSocket into Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, websocket

Is it possible to use standard [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket)'s to access a Firebase database instead of using their library. Specifically, I want to access the firebase real-time database using only vanilla javascript. Is that even feasible?

Comment: Sure, if you want to reverse engineer the wire protocol.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In most modern browsers the Firebase client communicates with its back-end over web sockets. But the wire protocol it uses is [not documented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44235551/documentation-for-firebase-websocket-protocol), and may change over time. Then again, you could study the [open-source JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk) to get a pretty good idea of how it works under the hood.

Alternatively, you could build your custom client library on top of the [Firebase REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start), which is fully documented. It includes support for [Streaming from the REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-streaming), which gets you many of the advantages of the Web Socket implementation without relying on an undocumented protocol.