# Using Firebase authentication and Firestore in China

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

Using Firebase stack for chrome extensions :) However, have one BIG problem.

Users located in China cant use the app since Google is blocked there thus Firebase authentication fails ... well, one option is to use VPN but in terms of user experience, it's a big No No ...  is there any better way to resolve/workaround this issue

Using mainly firebase auth (Google provider) and Firestore

Can use somehow custom tokens to resolve this?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

Or external authentication service combined with firebase, in this case, need to have authenticated access to firestore as well

Comment: even you solve the auth, arenot you still blocked using Firestore ?

Comment: @WeiChingLin yep, firestore is offline as well here ... :(

Comment: Im thinking of service-worker proxy, do any one success with it?

Comment: @WeiChingLin Iam not familiar with that, can you give more info

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create an API on HEROKU. Make all your Oauth and every call made for firebase go through the API. This API will only bridge all information between CHINA and GoogleServices (Firebase) since the great firewall blocks them.

Comment: I suggest heroku.. But you can also use other hosting service.. Always make sure they pass the great firewall. There is some service to verify that : https://en.greatfire.org/analyzer

Comment: Azure too is able to go through the greatfirewall.

Comment: thanks, yep, that what I eventually found myself doing

Comment: @alexpov how did you manage to reroute your frontend code? Did you have to rewrite firebase js library yourself? I can't seem to find a reasonable way for this :/

Comment: @eddyP23 I haven't tried yet, but what I'm thinking is: Use "AWS API Gateway" or "Google Endpoint" to reroute API request to "AWS Lamba" or "Cloud Function" which runs Nodejs when evoked. Then use "Firebase Admin SDK" to write code in Nodejs.

Comment: @eddyP23 You don't "reroute your frontend code", you "reroute your frontend request"

Comment: @ChristopheChenel I've never used Heroku before and this is the only thing I've been able to find regarding creating an API on Heroku, is this what you're referring to?  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mean-apps-restful-api

Comment: @NaheleAllan-Moon yes this is it.

Comment: @ChristopheChenel how do you implement this?

Comment: @ChristopheChenel this seems all viable for rest api calls. But what if you want for instance to listen on a document collection in Firestore? Another interesting case is Google Deep Links. Any ideas / comments on that?

Comment: @Daniel Maybe you could make your WebApp from heroku to manage all communication with a websocket and bridge the observable from client to firebase and vice-versa. I found this question that looks like what you ask : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48734290/javascript-websocket-into-firebase 

Also, I don't know what are the intents for the Google Deep Links, is it an integration of google ads ? If so, I don't think you should put google ads for an app dedicated for Chinese customer. The company "Baidu" should be better for this case.

Comment: @ChristopheChenel Thanks a lot for the tip. Highly appreciate. Deep links are a unification of universal link for iOS and Android app links to get the same behaviour on both platforms. Essentially Google hosts a mini website to do the proper forwarding. They are great for app referrals but if the app cannot be placed into the Chinese App store it would only work for the Android version.

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42605566/can-firebase-be-used-as-a-database-in-china-now relevant information on the topic discussed here.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution may be to set up a proxy server to forward your apps requests to Firebase.