# Is there a way to query for Firestore in China?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, bridge, great-firewall-of-china

It seems like the queries for Firestore are blocked in China, as are many services of Google. Is there a way to bridge Firestore to China?

I managed to find a post on bridging Firebase authentication ([Using Firebase authentication and Firestore in China](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52308437/using-firebase-authentication-and-firestore-in-china)), but that forgoes the realtime features quintessential of Firebase's services.

If there isn't a simple solution to this, what would be a good direction to explore this on?

Comment: This article might help: https://medium.com/faun/firebase-accessing-firestore-and-firebase-through-a-proxy-server-c6c6029cddb1

Comment: Hello. I am googling this but I cannot find a clear statement that tells me FireStore is really blocked in China. Could you please share a reference?