# Cloud firestore integration for chinese version of the app

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a multilingual app and I need to integrate Cloud Firestore into my app. I want to confirm, is Cloud Firestore can be integrated for the Chinese version of the app or I need to look for some alternate solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can save data in any language you want in a Cloud Firestore document as long as the field in which you are saving the data is a [String that is UTF-8 encoded](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types).

**Edit:**

According to your last comment:

> Will it work in the countries that don't allow Google like China?

Currently, Firestore is **only** available in the locations that are specified in the [Regional locations table](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/locations#location-r). Regarding China, there's no prediction for that, as also @gso_gabriel mentioned in his answer from the following post:

- [Firebase still blocked in China?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62317295/firebase-still-blocked-in-china)

Comment: Cloud Firestore is owned by Google. Will it work in the countries that don't allow Google like China?

Comment: That's some kind of a different question. However, please take a look at my updated answer.